# Hadoop 3.0.3 workers file vs slaves

Tags: hadoop

In the /etc/hadoop folder is there a difference between the workers file or slaves file you have to create? Also for 3.0.3 do i still need to create a masters file for the namenode?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, slaves are no longer used.  After hours of plugging my hairs why the data nodes are starting, I found the hard way "workers" file is the one you should configure not slaves.

If you do it would be neglected.  At least to me.  Just copy the content of slave to workers. It worked.

Hope this helps.